# Displaying selected value in a drop down with values from the database

Tags: laravel

I have a drop down that i am populating from the database with this method

```
public function view($id)
{
    $id = request()->segment(2);
    $items = Role::all(['name', 'display_name']);

    return view('text.ServicesEditUser', compact('items'));
}
```

I am then displaying the select box this way in the database

```
<select name="user_role" class="form-control">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->name}}">{{$item->display_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

The select box generated is being used during the creation of a record. However, i now want to edit the form and i want to mark as selected the option saved in the database.

Before when i knew the `name` and `display_name` i could easily do this

```
<option value="admin" @if ($role->name == "admin")selected="selected" @endif>Admin</option>
<option value="user" @if ($role->name == "user")selected="selected" @endif>User</option>
<option value="superuser" @if ($role->name == "superuser")selected="selected" @endif>Superuser</option>
```

How can i mark as selected the saved value in the database?.

This is the roles table

[image]

This is the role user table

[image]

Comment: How is the Role saved in the database? And why did you pass `id` to view function and doesn't use it?

Comment: @DestinatioN I made an update to include the screenshot of roles table.

Comment: Can you show how you fetch the role of the user? What does $role in the view contain?

Comment: @Sandeesh `$items = Role::all(['name', 'display_name']);`

Comment: @GeoffreyIsle `Role::all` fetches all roles not the roles a user has

Comment: @DestinatioN I need to fetch all roles since its an edit form and the user might need to pick another role.

Comment: Yeah but you want to mark the role a user already has

Comment: How you fetch the current of the user to compare for the selection. You must have something to fetch the role. Like `$user->role()->name`

Comment: @DestinatioN oh yeah, silly me, i get you now. That can be done like so `$user_role = Ru::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();` but i will have to add role_user table with role_name, role_id and access it using `Ru` in the model

Comment: Alright gimme a sec i'll whip up some code

Answer (score 3):

Controller

```
$currentRole = Ru::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
$roles = Role::all(['name', 'display_name']);

return view('text.ServicesEditUser', compact('roles', 'currentRole'));
```

View

```
<select name="user_role" class="form-control">
    @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{$role->name}}" {{ $role->name === $currentRole->name? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$role->display_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

By the way, you shouldn't have a model for your pivot table. You need to use relationships to access the data. With proper relationship setup, you can do something like this.

```
$currentRole = auth()->user()->role
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct, you have the roles as records in the database...
Instead you should have a table users with a field role and maybe link it to the role table. And select the saved value from the user table not the role table...

Read more about how to build One-to-One Relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)